# Convert C++ '? :'conditional operators into python

Tags: python, c++

Could any please help me convert this to python? I don't how to translate the conditional operators from C++ into python?

```
Math.easeInExpo = function (t, b, c, d) {
return (t==0) ? b : c * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t/d - 1)) + b;
```

Comment: `return b if (t==0) else (c * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t/d - 1)) + b)` based on @frostnational 's link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def easeInExpo( t, b, c, d ):
    return b if t == 0 else c * pow( 2, 10 * (t/d - 1) ) + b
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if` / `else`:

```
return b if t == 0 else c * pow(2, 10 * (t/d - 1)) +b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (t==0) ? b : c * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t/d - 1)) + b;
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (t == 0)
{
    return b;
}
else
{
    return c * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t/d - 1)) + b;
}
```

Hopefully that's enough to get you started.